Help with a new partition
An acquaintance installed Linux Mint 17.3 Mate on an Asus Mini PC for me in 2016.
Support for 19.3 has ended and I first asked for help in Germany. ( without success)
I need help with the new formatting of the 128 GB SSD .
I live remotely in a small town in Panama .
I can be reached with Skype or Signal Messenger.
Kind regards
Un conocido me instaló Linux Mint 17.3 Mate en un Asus Mini PC en 2016.
El soporte para 19.3 ha terminado y primero pedí ayuda en Alemania. ( sin éxito)
Necesito ayuda para reformatear el SSD de 128 GB .
Vivo remotamente en un pequeño pueblo de Panamá .
Me pueden contactar con Skype o Signal Messenger.
Saludos

Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are on-topic here, refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Linux Mint forum. (One advantage of Ubuntu is its many support options, you opted for Linux Mint so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux found in the on-topic link)

If you are asking for help formatting a storage device to install Ubuntu upon, simply let the Ubuntu installer handle it. That's one of the basic tasks installers do. If you need something different, your question should clearly explain what help you seek with Ubuntu.
